# Directly update file content through Google Drive API (V3)

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

this is more like a confirmation of my personal finding rather than asking for solution.
So I would like to confirm that there is no way you can directly read, write/update the content of your files stored in google drive through the google drive API.

(Note: I am aware that google docs api exists, but the file types I would like to modify is just simple text file (.txt), config file (.json) and excel (.xlsx, .xlsm))

If you would like to do so, the only way is to download the file and save it locally, read/modify the file locally. And to update the file in drive, you then have to, after modifying the file locally, upload the modified file back to google drive and delete the original one.

Can anyone provide a "yes" or "no" to the above statement. And if "no", please provide any information (a link or a code snippet) about an example that successfully updates the file in Google drive through provided Google drive API.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also google api only allows you to read the file meta-data but does not allow you to access the file content.

Answer (score 0):

The Google drive api is a file storage api for the most part.   If you want to edit the contents of a file for example google docs or google sheets you need to use their respective apis.

However if this is for example a raw text file minetype `text/plain`.  Then it is possible to download the file into `memory` (not save to disk) then modify the text data within it and reupload it.

That is the only thing you can do as the api doesn't have a patch method for the file data there is only upload and download options.  To modify you would probably need to be able to edit only sections of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you have a working example? It seems the files().get(fileid) method only retrieve the file meta data, it seems like there is no way you can actually get the file content. I have tried execute(), executeAndDownloadTo() and executeMediaAsInputStream() and none of them worked